# check the given div is in the parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to check the given tag 'section' within the parent div.If the 'section' tag is not existing wrap the child  div with in 'section' tag.

```js
jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 34) {
    alert('hello');
    jQuery(".child").wrap("<section class='panell'>Hello</section>");
  }
});
```

```css
.panell { border:1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" style="background-color:red;min-height:100vh;">
  <div class="child">
   World

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to check the section tag is exist with in class 'parent' and append wrap the child div with in section tag

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap child only if which is the direct child of parent element.

```js
jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 34) {
    alert('hello');
    jQuery(".parent>.child").wrap("<section class='panell'>Hello</section>");
  }
});
```

```css
  .panell { border:5px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" style="background-color:red;min-height:100vh;">
  <div class="child">


  </div>
</div>
```